# Direct access to permission of meeting field in database of adobe connect

Tags: adobe, adobe-connect

According to official [docs](https://www.connectusers.com/tutorials/2020/02/managing_access_to_your_room/index.php)
There are 4 options to control access to Adobe Connect room in the New Meeting Wizard. I want direct access to this field in the database, the question is which field and which table represents to this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't suggest to alter database directly, because future update may overwrite the changes.

Best way to do what you are trying to achive is to use Adobe Connect XML API  [Adobe Connect Web Services](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/webservices/introduction-connect-web-services.html)